# Do-loop in SAS-IML

Tags: matrix, sas, sas-macro, do-loops, sas-iml

I want to use a macro do loop inside proc iml like so:

```
%Let Tab1=FirstTable;
%Let Tab2=SecondTable;
%Let Tab3=ThirdTable;

*&Tab1-3 have been initialised as sas datasets;   

proc iml;

* This works;

use &Tab1;
read all into Mat3;
print Mat3;


* This doesn't work;

%Macro Define_mx;
    %do i=1 %to 2;
    use &Tab&i;
    read all into Mat&i ;
   %end;
  %Mend Define_mx;
%Define_mx;

*The two matrixes have not been initialised;

print Mat1;
print Mat2;
quit;
```

In reality I will have to initialise like 50 matrixes so a do-loop is necessary. 
I can't figure out why the loop can't see &Tab&i as a macro variable.
I also tried a workaround with a normal (non-macro) do-loop using substr to concatenate the variable names but it didn't work either. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Double amperstand on Tab... I'm an idiot.

Comment: Brilliant!  Please submit your solution as an answer and accept it.  This is definitely a sufficiently common mistake that it's worth having as a solution in StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the macro should be:

```
%Macro Define_mx;
 %do i=1 %to 2;
   use &&Tab&i;
   read all into Mat&i ;
 %end;
 %Mend Define_mx;
%Define_mx;
```

The second amperstand on Tab is necessary as without it the macro processor would try to interpret &Tab as a macro variable (which does not exist). Thus, when trying to concatenate multiple macro variables to create a new one, use &&.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SAS/IML 12.1 (released with 9.3m2), there is an even simpler way.
The [USE statement supports dereferencing data set names,](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/65547/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_whatsnew9_sect002.htm) like this:

```
ds = "MyData";
use (ds);
```

Furthermore, as I show in my [article on using the VALSET function](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/03/23/indirect-assignment-how-to-create-and-use-matrices-named-x1-x2-xn/), the SAS/IML language supports the VALSET function, which can dynamically create matrices named Mat1, Mat2, and so on. 
You can combine these features to eliminate the macros entirely:

```
data a b c;                 /* create sample data sets */
x=1;y=2; output;
x=2;y=3; output;
run;

proc iml;
dsnames = {a b c};          /* names of data sets */
do i = 1 to ncol(dsnames);
   use (dsnames[i]);        /* open each data set */
   read all into X;
   close (dsname);
   MatName = "Mat"+strip(char(i)); /* create Mat1, Mat2,... */
   call valset(MatName, X);        /* assign values from data set */
end;
show names;
```

Comment: Getting rid of the macro was my goal at some point also. I guess you could write `call valset("Mat"+strip(char(i)));` with your solution to make it more neat. Unfortunately, I'm still on 9.2. As I understand this solution won't work with this version ?